# MALLET topic modeling OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, out-of-memory, mallet

I use MALLET for topic modeling.
http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/topics.php

First, I try to import the training document set following the instruction.

```
bin/mallet import-dir --input /data/topic-input --output topic-input.mallet --keep-sequence --remove-stopwords
```

I always get `OutOfMemoryError`, although I change `"bin/mallet.bat"` according to the following page. 
[Mallet topic modelling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168342/mallet-topic-modelling)

I set `set MALLET_MEMORY=32G`.

My data set size is 30GB.

Computer memory is sufficient.

I get the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3658)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:201)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.substring(AbstractStringBuilder.java:909)
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.subSequence(StringBuffer.java:473)
    at cc.mallet.extract.StringSpan.constructTokenText(StringSpan.java:49)
    at cc.mallet.extract.StringSpan.<init>(StringSpan.java:33)
    at cc.mallet.pipe.CharSequence2TokenSequence.pipe(CharSequence2TokenSequence.java:68)
    at cc.mallet.pipe.Pipe$SimplePipeInstanceIterator.next(Pipe.java:294)
    at cc.mallet.pipe.Pipe$SimplePipeInstanceIterator.next(Pipe.java:282)
    at cc.mallet.pipe.Pipe$SimplePipeInstanceIterator.next(Pipe.java:290)
    at cc.mallet.pipe.Pipe$SimplePipeInstanceIterator.next(Pipe.java:282)
    at cc.mallet.pipe.Pipe$SimplePipeInstanceIterator.next(Pipe.java:290)
    at cc.mallet.pipe.Pipe$SimplePipeInstanceIterator.next(Pipe.java:282)
    at cc.mallet.pipe.Pipe$SimplePipeInstanceIterator.next(Pipe.java:290)
    at cc.mallet.pipe.Pipe$SimplePipeInstanceIterator.next(Pipe.java:282)
    at cc.mallet.types.InstanceList.addThruPipe(InstanceList.java:267)
    at cc.mallet.classify.tui.Text2Vectors.main(Text2Vectors.java:312)
$ bin/mallet import-dir --input ../Text --output topic-input.mallet --keep-sequence --remove-stopwords
Labels = 
   ../Text
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3658)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:201)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.substring(AbstractStringBuilder.java:909)
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.subSequence(StringBuffer.java:473)
    at cc.mallet.extract.StringSpan.constructTokenText(StringSpan.java:49)
    at cc.mallet.extract.StringSpan.<init>(StringSpan.java:33)
    at cc.mallet.pipe.CharSequence2TokenSequence.pipe(CharSequence2TokenSequence.java:68)
    at cc.mallet.pipe.Pipe$SimplePipeInstanceIterator.next(Pipe.java:294)
    at cc.mallet.pipe.Pipe$SimplePipeInstanceIterator.next(Pipe.java:282)
    at cc.mallet.pipe.Pipe$SimplePipeInstanceIterator.next(Pipe.java:290)
    at cc.mallet.pipe.Pipe$SimplePipeInstanceIterator.next(Pipe.java:282)
    at cc.mallet.pipe.Pipe$SimplePipeInstanceIterator.next(Pipe.java:290)
    at cc.mallet.pipe.Pipe$SimplePipeInstanceIterator.next(Pipe.java:282)
    at cc.mallet.pipe.Pipe$SimplePipeInstanceIterator.next(Pipe.java:290)
    at cc.mallet.pipe.Pipe$SimplePipeInstanceIterator.next(Pipe.java:282)
    at cc.mallet.types.InstanceList.addThruPipe(InstanceList.java:267)
    at cc.mallet.classify.tui.Text2Vectors.main(Text2Vectors.java:312)
```

How can I fix this problem? Thank you.

Comment: is it trying to read 30 GB into memory ? profile it and let us know if it is attempting to create one huge instance of String ?

Comment: I'm not sure how MALLET works actually, but it seems the program tries to read 30 GB text directory.

Comment: 30G is a *ton* of data! Do you have access to a machine with more memory? If not, I can run the analysis if you send me an email.

Answer (score 7):

You can increase the memory that mallet uses. Where is your home directory of mallet? In the home directory of mallet you have `bin` directory.
In `bin` directory open the mallet file in a text editor and set "MEMORY" to the upper value. The default value for "MEMORY" is **1g**. You can set it up to **4g**.